# iPhone Twitter app style Searchbar animation?

Tags: iphone, animation, twitter, searchbar

I'd like to use the Twitter iPhone app style searchbar animation. When you click on the searchbar the navigation bar is hidden and the searchbar moves up to the top of the screen with keyboard popping up. I can do the Navigation bar hidden animation thing using this...

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    return  YES;
}
```

I want to move the searchBar upwards to the area vacated by the hidden navigationBar. I'm guessing its by some CAAnimation or something like that.

Comment: Not sure, but i think its a default behavior of the UISearchBarController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UISearchBarController implements it by default. Should have figured it out though ;)